# Windows Phone - remove items from ListPicker and refresh datasource in full mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I have a ListPicker whose items source is an observable collection. I added a context menu to this list so that the user can long press any item to edit/delete it. I have two problems regarding delete:

1- if I remove any item from observable collection, the change is not reflected in full mode, I have to close the picker and re-open, then, I can see that the item is removed

2- if the item to be deleted is that last item, removing it will fire exception:  `System.InvalidOperationException: SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value`

this is a part of my xaml:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Shipping Addresses" Name="lst_ShippingAddresses" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly">
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AddressCaption}" Margin="0,10" FontSize="26"/>
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="EditShippingAddress"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="DeleteShippingAddress"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

and this is the delete function:

```
private void DeleteShippingAddress(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
        ShippingAddress address = item.DataContext as ShippingAddress;

        if (lst_DeliveryAddresses.SelectedItem == address)
        {
            if (lst_DeliveryAddresses.Items.Count == 1) // last element in list
            {
                shippingAddresses.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                if (lst_DeliveryAddresses.SelectedIndex == 0) // first element
                    lst_DeliveryAddresses.SelectedIndex = lst_DeliveryAddresses.SelectedIndex + 1;
                else
                    lst_DeliveryAddresses.SelectedIndex = lst_DeliveryAddresses.SelectedIndex - 1;
                shippingAddresses.Remove(address);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            shippingAddresses.Remove(address);
        }
    });
}
```

How can I refresh the datasource in full mode? I tried `lst_DeliveryAddresses.UpdateLayout()` but no use. 
And how can I clear the datasource of ListPicker without getting this exception?

Please help, thanks !

Comment: Why do you need to check if it is the first or last item during delete operation?

Comment: because if I'm deleting the selected item, I will get System.InvalidOperationException, so I must select another item before deleting it. If it's the first element and count > 1, make next item selected, otherwise make the previous one selected.